# My failed audit shows another user

Tags: bug, review, design, review-audits, review-suspension

I got a review ban when my mouse lagged. This is what I'm seeing now:

[image]

Looks normal. However, when I visit [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7144318), I see this:

[image]

For that very review I'm seeing another user listed who passed the audit.

Comment: The username is public, so there's no point in censoring it (as long as the review link is provided). The real question is, does SE show the latest user who got the audit?

Comment: Audits are being reused as far as I know. It shouldn't show the other persons review though. On the other hand, you can see the users who accepted or rejected your suggested edits too.